# Batching dots over another with same values in a dotplot in R

Tags: r, colors, plot, duplicates

I created a dotplot with R with the following source code:

`dotplot(mass_movement ~ quantity, data=mm_strat, groups=stratigraphy, cex=1.5, pch=19)`

The data looks like this:

```
quantity | mass_movement | stratigraphy
---------+---------------+------------
    1    |     slide     | geology_1
    2    |     fall      | geology_1
    4    |     slide     | geology_2
    6    |     topple    | geology_3
    6    |     topple    | geology_2
```

When I plot this, you can see the types of mass_movement on the y-axis, the quantity on the x-axis and with default colors the dots, which are representing the stratigraphy.

Now, I want to set my own colors for the dots and to create a legend within the plot.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
mm_strat$color[mm_strat$stratigraphy == geology_1] <- "red"
mm_strat$color[mm_strat$stratigraphy == geology_2] <- "blue"
...

dotplot(mass_movement ~ quantity. data=mm_strat, groups=stratigraphy, col=mm_strat$color, cex=1.5, pch=19)`
```

The mass_movement "topple" appears in two geologys with the same quantity. So you can't see two dots. Is there a way to batch one dot over another dot??